# Custom layers in Keras -- custom weights

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, weighted-data

I am trying to understand how to build custom layers in Keras and I went through a couple examples: [here](https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/) and [here](https://sparrow.dev/keras-custom-layer/). The syntax is, of course, similar, but in non of the cases it is addressed why weights are declared the way they are. For instance, how do I constrain weights to be binary?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am really curious about why you want to restrict weights to be binary.

Comment: I need the weights to be binary as it is required for my assignment. The more general question is how to control what values the weights can be assigned by the NN.

Comment: I'm really curious why your professor wants to restrict weights to be binary.

Comment: Because it is cheaper to store a binary sequence, than a float, I guess. Why is it so interesting.